# How much space is required to install Python + Numpy and Matplotlib libraries on Windows?

Tags: python, package, windows-10

The question in the Title is clear enough. But I haven't been able to get a precise answer.
Does anyone knows how heavy are those packages once installed on W10?

Answer (score 2):

For my machine:

Numpy: ~54Mb

Matplotlib: ~21Mb

Python 3.8: ~97Mb